# Elastic: Failed to resolve config path

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm banging my head against the screen with this problem.  I'm trying to configure stopwords for an index.  This works on my local system, an Ubuntu system.

Using Elastic 1.7.2

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: 34bbe264-ad79-de46-d5cd-293c5a9a1584" -d '{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_english": {
          "type":           "english",
          "stopwords_path": "stopwords/stopwords_en.txt" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}' 'http://10.40.1.55:9200/my_index'
```

This is the trace caused from using the Java API (both cURL and Java produce the error)

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.env.FailedToResolveConfigException: Failed to resolve config path [/stopwords/stopwords_en.txt], tried file path [/stopwords/stopwords_en.txt], path file [/etc/elasticsearch/stopwords/stopwords_en.txt], and classpath
        at org.elasticsearch.env.Environment.resolveConfig(Environment.java:213)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.Analysis.getWordList(Analysis.java:230)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.Analysis.parseWords(Analysis.java:165)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.Analysis.parseStopWords(Analysis.java:185)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.Analysis.parseStopWords(Analysis.java:181)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.StandardAnalyzerProvider.<init>(StandardAnalyzerProvider.java:53)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor135.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:54)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:98)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$5$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:781)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:837)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.InjectorImpl$5.get(InjectorImpl.java:777)
        at org.elasticsearch.common.inject.assistedinject.FactoryProvider2.invoke(FactoryProvider2.java:221)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.create(Unknown Source)
```

Permissions on /etc/elasticsearch are wide open.

```
drwxrwxrwx   3 root root  4096 Sep 30 15:03 ./
drwxr-xr-x 111 root root  4096 Sep 18 16:01 ../
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root 13476 Apr 27 10:07 elasticsearch.yml*
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root  2054 Sep 14 11:51 logging.yml*
-rwxr--r--   1 root root  4588 Sep 30 15:03 stopwords_en.txt*
```

There is nothing in the `elasticsearch.log`

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that ES is trying to resolve your file from `/etc/elasticsearch/stopwords/stopwords_en.txt` and not `/etc/elasticsearch/stopwords_en.txt`

Comment: I have updated the request to match the response.

Comment: I have posted the solution below

Answer (score 0):

This was a result of clustering while I didn't know.  Someone installed Elastic for another project on the same network.

The log states that it found a master

```
[2015-09-30 15:34:30,498][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Bedlam II] detected_master [Abominatrix][CIhwAycJTzufgmB4cw0utQ][p-v00284][inet[/10.40.1.54:9300]], added {[Abominatrix][CIhwAycJTzufgmB4cw0utQ][p-v00284][inet[/10.40.1.54:9300]],}, reason: zen-disco-receive(from master [[Abominatrix][CIhwAycJTzufgmB4cw0utQ][p-v00284][inet[/10.40.1.54:9300]]])
[2015-09-30 15:34:30,642][INFO ][http                     ] [Bedlam II] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.40.1.55:9200]}
```